# Calculate difference of two values with subquery

Tags: mysql

I have a status-table in which I store completion scores of user profiles. Every day, the listing score of each user profile is saved.
I want to know which profile score improve over time: e.g. those that have a higher score yesterday than two weeks ago. For that, I want to use a subquery which I can't get to work.

Currently, I have this:

```
SELECT user_id, completion_score
FROM user_profile_stats
WHERE date = curdate() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
AND completion_score > (
  SELECT user_id, completion_score
  FROM user_profile_stats
  WHERE date = curdate() - INTERVAL 14 DAY
  )
```

I get the error that the subquery returns more than 1 row (which is correct). After searching on this forum I found that I had to use IN instead of >, but then my query is not what I want it to return.

I'd appreciate your explanation on what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LIMIT keyword to restrict the output to 1 record

Refer http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx

I hope this will help to fix this issue